# How do I copy a string array to an int32 array?

Tags: c#

I'm a noob at C# and stackoverflow. In one of my exercises I was asked to create program and ask the user to enter a series of numbers separated by comma then find the maximum of the numbers and display it on the console. For example, if the user enters “5, 3, 8, 1, 4", the program should display 8.

On startup the user is asked to enter a series of numbers seperated by commas.
The result is a string array that I then split into substrings. The issue lies in converting this substring array into an integer array.

I've made use of the Array.copy method from a string array to int array and the result is:

```
                System.ArrayTypeMismatchException
```

[The console program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2dat.png)

Comment: `Array.Copy` cannot convert strings to `int`s. You should try to look into `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse`. You can use them with `Array.ConvertAll` or Linq `.Select`, or write an explicit loop with `foreach` or `for`.

Comment: How about _userInput.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(item => { int.TryParse(item, out int value); return value; }).Max();_

Comment: [Do not post code as image.](https://textnot.pictures/) Post as formatted text.

Comment: ^^ Or a little more verbose: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gr3HEW

Comment: Because existing answers use it: Are you allowed to use `System.Linq`? Or are you supposed to code the "find max" explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because the `Array.Copy()` method expects both arrays to be of the **same type**. You cannot use this method because one array consists of strings and the other array consists of integers. I recommend the following method;

Let's import the necessary namespaces.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;
```

Firstly, we separate the comma separated numbers with the `Split()` method and go through each of them one by one with foreach. We add these numbers to the list by converting them from string to integer with the `Convert.ToInt32()` method and finally we pull the largest number in the list with the `Max()`method.

```
    string input = "5, 3, 8, 1, 4";
    var values = input.Split(',');
    
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
    foreach(var item in values){
        numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.Trim()));
    }
    
    int maxNumber = numbers.Max();
```

Comment: [`item.Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-8.0#system-string-trim)

Comment: This is solving _the assignment_ but not really explaining why OP encountered the Exception ... maybe you can add a paragraph about that to make this answer really great?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it sort of wrong. You need to first convert every string to an int and make a new array out of that, then get the highest number. And please paste code not as images but as code blocks (surround your code by three backticks ```
like this
``` but put new lines before and after your code) or put it at Pastebin https://pastebin.com.

First, for the sake of easiness, let's import LINQ which will add a method to arrays:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

Then, here's the final code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter comma-separated values.");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] values = input.Split(',');
        values = values.Select(v => v.Replace(" ", "")).ToArray();
        int[] values_int = values.Select<string, int>(v =>
        {
            int output;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(v, out output))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return output;
        }).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(values_int.Max());
    }
}
```

Here, we use `Select()` to apply code to every member of an array and put it into a new array through the `=` operator. The first instance removes all spaces, and the second one converts them to integers. We use `Int32.TryParse` to convert `string`s into `int`s, but in case something goes wrong (not a number is out inside), we just replace that value with zero. Then, we return what was converted, in case we didn't return 0 before. The `out output` tells the function to modify the variable, and not a local copy. Then we use another LINQ method, `Max()`, to pick the highest value from `values_int`. If every value was incorrect (say, `a,b, ,,,c,`), then it will simply be 0. Play around with it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zM343H

Comment: _"or put it at Pastebin"_ - actually, no. Don't. Questions should contain all relevant information without external links if so possible.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the `ArrayTypeMismatchException` is that [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-8.0) presumes that both arrays are of the same type. So you cannot simply copy a `string[]` into a `int[]`.

---

So the user should be able to enter "5, 3, 8, 1, 4" and you find the max-integer?

First task is to *split* the string to multiple, so use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0):

```
string input = "5, 3, 8, 1, 4";
string[] numbers = input.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

Next task is to parse each one to `int`. Since that can fail you should try-parse them. However a quick and dirty solution that assumes that the input is valid is:

```
int[] integers = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, int.Parse);
```

the safer way is:

```
int[] integers = numbers.Select(n => int.TryParse(n, out int i) ? i : new int?())
                        .Where(i => i.HasValue).Select(i => i.Value).ToArray();
```

The last task is to find the max value, therefore you can also use LINQ:

```
int maxValue = integers.Max();
```

Comment: Just being nitpicky: Given, that this is an assignment, OP _may_ not be allowed to use Linq (if the point or one of them was to code a "find max" algorithm). I asked for clarification, but they have not reacted, yet.

Comment: @Fildor: Agreed. I don't know, OP should have clarified it then. However, if i would give this as an exercise i would be happy if i got solutions which are concise and easy to understand :)

Comment: Of course. I also think the main point of the question was to explain why the Exception happened in the first place. So, ... too much perhaps, yes.

Answer (score 0):

try this It worked.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace HelloWorld
{

  class Program
 {
      static void Main()
     {
          string[] stringArray = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
          int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.Length];

          for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
           {
              int.TryParse(stringArray[i], out int value);
              intArray[i] = value;
           }
          foreach (int num in intArray)
          {
             Console.WriteLine(num);
          }
  }}
```